# What is the best way to save the items of listview when the activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, database, listview

I am making an app in which i am showing contacts to the user in a list view.I want to show the same list view to the user until and unless some changes are made to the contact list.The question arises here that when the activity is destroyed and till the user come back to the activity having the contact listview,`Where shall i store the items of the listview as to show them to the user again`?I think there are 3 options available:

```
1. Sqlite database
2. SdCard
3. Shared Preferences
```

I am not able to take the decision about `which will be the best option for saving the items` so as to retrieve them later.In my case the number of items in the list view may be upto 1000.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to store permanently use Shared Preferences.and one more option is onSaveInstance().it method call on orientation changes and going to other activity.in both condition your activity get destroyed..so better is to use onSaveInstance()

Comment: what if the user kills the app and start it again?In that case the state of the activity will be retained or not.

Comment: see if you come one apps to your apps(which is open already) onSaveInstance will work .but you will shut down your app and restart again then it ll not.better use one of them(above)

Comment: see this 5. http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/android-basics-managing-activity-states-part-i/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go with  SQLite database as it is protected , you can also use sdcard and any File format like property file , csv ...etc to save your list detail , however sdcard media is shared with all application and accessible from user also .With so many contact I will not recommend shared preference as fetch detail and running query is not possible  like  in SQLite .

Comment: So according to you using Sqlite database is the best option in my case?

Comment: Nop just tell me how frequently u need to update contact ie in database and how much content you access at one time to display in list ........... as accessing much of record and displaying in list will slow your application , then instead you can use CursorAdapter along with listview.

Comment: My need is to make the contact list from phone when the app is installed first,then to update it using content observer and to show it to the user for some contact selection purpose.Here i am not getting how to save the items of the listview having contact so as to be shown later when needed.

Comment: please suggest what to do in that case to achieve the purpose.

Comment: what are you trying  to do with your application ,, ie by fetching  list record using content observer.

Comment: no fetching contacts from phone and showing them to the user.

Comment: you can fetch it again when your application resume or restart .. no need to save the contact,

Comment: But again fetching it from phone takes time,am i right?Suppose if there are 1000 contacts present in the phone,then how to fetch all of them at the short notice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21633/discussion-between-user1726619-and-vipin-sahu)

Comment: fetch the record with the following suggested way will also take time that why i recommended to use cursor adapter with  list view